# How to export an h2o model in JS or EXCEL?

Tags: h2o

I need to export an H2o model in Javascript or Excel.

I know how to export models using JAVA, Python and R. I want to do the same for JS and Excel. 
An idea could be to load the exported model in mojo to the sever and then use the REST API to perform model evaluation. Unfortunately we cannot succeed in performing the loading (we have opened an issue here regarding this specific problem). 
Do you have any idea of how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pointer to a git repo that has an example of how to host an H2O-3 MOJO in a REST API:

- https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan